# How to access navigationOptions defined in screen component with custom navigation header set in defaultNavigationOptions

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Here's the setup:

TabNavigator { Stack A, Stack B, Stack C}

I am defining a `defaultNavigationOptions` in the second parameter of my createStackNavigator() function that is building Stacks A,B & C. That specific line of code is passing through the props:

```
defaultNavigationOptions: {
      header: props => <NavSearchHeader {...props} />
    },
```

In my screen components I'm assigning a function to the static `navigationOptions`. For example, an account screen pushed to StackC is assigning a headerRight:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
   return {
      headerRight: (
        <Button
          onPress={navigation.getParam('logout')}
          title="logout"
        />
      ),
    };
}
```

**Inside of my custom `NavSearchHeader` component, how can I access the navigation options returned from the static `navigationOptions` defined in the screen component so I can add the passed component to my own header implementation?**

Comment: What are the values for NavSearchHeader?

Comment: Which values specifically? The navigation props?

Comment: I think this is impossible because the two are not parents and children.